# Soap message builder that returns a String instead of making a request

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, axis

I have a WSDL and a remote SOAP 1.2 endpoint. I'm looking for a tool that generates somes Pojo files and exposes a library that returns a String representation of SOAP envelop, and that does not make the request by it self (I have another utility classes to make that).

This is the use case that I want to have :

```
UserPojo user = new UserPojo();
user.setFirstName('foo');
user.setLastName('bar');
user.setId('123456');

SetUserNamesBody body = new SetUserNamesBody();
body.setUser(user);
Header header = new Header();
HeaderAttribute header1 = new HeaderAttribute('param1', 'value1');
HeaderAttribute header2 = new HeaderAttribute('param2', 'value2');

header.addHeaderAttribute(header1);
header.addHeaderAttribute(header2);

SoapEnveloppe enveloppe = new SoapEnveloppe();
enveloppe.addHeader(header);
String stringSoapMessage  = enveloppe.getStringPresentation();
```

Assuming that SetUserNamesBody and UserPojo are generated the utility (axis like).

Any ideas ?

---

**EDIT**

It's equivalent to having jaxws generated classes and getting the soap message xml without sending the request to the endpoint.

Comment: Not related to POJO, but related to SOAP->String conversion: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/OutputSOAPmessagewithXMLtransformer.htm

Comment: Yeah, but is there any kind of library that can generate that for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Mock Services](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html) in [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)?

[image]

> The MockResponse editor is very similar to the standard SoapUI Request editor , but instead of requests, we'll edit responses. The Incoming Request view is still very useful; it shows the last received request to the operation which is useful for debugging client calls, including attachments and HTTP headers.